# node.js server does not response to the client?

Tags: node.js

I'm a newer to node.I wirte this test case to r/w mysql databases. However, after click the register button. The table in the database is  updated, while the client has no response.
At start,it shows the socket hang up error. After i update my node to v.0.8.25. It show nothing now.
Anyone can help me with this?

my client code is very simple:

```
var username = $('#username').val().trim();
var pwd = $('#password').val().trim();
$.post('http://myserver/' + 'reg', {username : username , password: pwd}, function(data){
    window.alert( data);
});
```

my server code:

```
app.get( "/reg" , route.reg);
app.post( "/reg", route.doreg);

in route.js:
exports.doreg = function( req ,res){
var msg = req.body;

userOperator.createUser( msg.username , msg.password ,  function( err , user){
   if( err ){
       res.send( {code: 501});
       res.end();
   }else {
       res.send({ code:200, username: user.name , password: user.password});
   }
});
};enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not `end`ing the response if no error is thrown.

```
else {
       res.send({ code:200, username: user.name , password: user.password});
       res.end(); //missing
}
```

BTW, the first argument to `send()` can be a status code:

```
 if( err ) {
       res.send(501);
 } else {
       res.send(200, username: user.name , password: user.password});
 }
 res.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  It still doesn't work. And I find it never step into the callback function in the client side:  $.post('http://myserver/' + 'reg', {username : username , password: pwd}, function(data){
    window.alert( data);